# Python List Loop Error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

What I am trying to do is to check if the values in 'dragonLoot' exists in the dictionairy 'inv' keys. If so I want to add 1 to that value, if not I want to create a new key with that value and add 1.

I Think I have gotten the if, else part correct but I some how struggeling to get it to loop and reciving a *TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str* error. Here is the code:

```
#Inventory and the Loot value
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

#Function to loop through the items in the list
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    item_total = 0
    for j, k in inventory.items():
        print(str(k) + ' ' + j)
        item_total += k
    print('Total number of items: %s' % str(item_total))

#Where the problem occur
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        if addedItems[i] in inventory.keys():
            #Edit: I see an error here now, but I will fix it after I get the loop working
            inventory[addedItems[i]] + 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(addedItems[i], 1)

inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

I have tryed alot of other solutions I have found here on StackOverflow but nothing does the trick. Is it maybe some other error I have caused that have nothing to do with the Loop itself?

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/*****/Dropbox/*****", line 19, in   <module>
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
File "C:/Users/*****/Dropbox/*****", line 14, in  addToInventory
if addedItems[i] in inventory.keys():
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/Dropbox/Programming/simpleGame.py", line 19, in <module>
    inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
  File "C:/Users/***/Dropbox/Programming/simpleGame.py", line 14, in addToInventory
    if addedItems[i] in inventory.keys():
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: FYI, you pretty much never need `.keys()` - the `in` operator on a dict will already check against the list of keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not using a Counter?

```
#Inventory and the Loot value
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

import collections
inv = collections.Counter(inv)
inv.update(dragonLoot)

print inv
```

produces

```
Counter({'gold coin': 45, 'rope': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'ruby': 1})
```

See [pymotw](http://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html) for more info on Counters

Comment: Did not know about Collections, will try it.

Comment: Python's standard library is your friend. Avoid re-inventing the wheel, unless it's for training purposes.

Comment: I got it now to work to change line 14 as Anand said but when I get it to work I will rewrite it with collections instead to try it out. Thank you! Edit: Yes, all of this is for training purposes, I am so bad with lists, dictionaries and functions so I figured "Why not add them all into a program and see how it goes" :)

Comment: OK. BTW, I have edited my answer, since things can be even simpler: a Counter can be updated in several ways and there's no need to mutate the list into a dicitonary. You can pass it the list directly (each element will count as 1). Have fun!

Comment: Just tried it out. How easy it became! Thank you once again, will remember it and study the standard library a bit more.

Comment: I am happy you find it useful and understand the importance of using optimised building blocks. [Python Module of the Week](http://pymotw.com/) is one of the most valuable resources on the standard library. Even in [paper format](http://doughellmann.com/pages/python-standard-library-by-example.html), it's well worth its weight! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the issue is here -

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        if addedItems[i] in inventory.keys(): #<--- guessing this is the line.
```

The thing is , when you do `for i in addedItems:` , it loops through the elements in the list, not the list indices. so `i` would be items like - `'gold coin'` , then `'dagger'` ,etc. Not the indices of the list, so you can just do the check as - `if i in inventory.keys():` . Code -

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        if i in inventory.keys():
            inventory[i] + 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(i, 1)
```

For your case, to count the number of items in a list, you can use - [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Example -

```
>>> import collections
>>> dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
>>> invt = dict(collections.Counter(dragonLoot))
>>> invt
{'ruby': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'gold coin': 3}
```

Comment: That did it, now it moved on to the other error at line 17 so I can fix it. Thank you!

Comment: All the places you have to use `i` instead of `addedItems[i]` . Updated that in the answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit late, I guess, but I'm doing the same tutorial. The solution I came up with is:

`def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in range(len(addedItems)):
        if addedItems[i] in inventory:
            inventory[addedItems[i]] += 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(addedItems[i],1)
    return inventory`

At least it works as it's supposed to. Hope it helps someone!